# Passing unicode char in XML

Tags: java, xml, unicode

We need to invoke some legacy APIs which expect `String.valueOf('\246')` in order to work properly. Since the input is in the form of XML we were wondering what string to put in the XML file to match `String.valueOf('\246')`.

Comment: You need a [numeric character reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference).

Comment: Or simpy `ö`. Be careful with the file encoding then, though.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the encoding you are using when you write your XML.  If you are using UTF-8, then you can add a prolog like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

The XML parser should be able to read any properly encoded characters in any supported character encoding.  Support for UTF-8 is mandatory for any XML parser.

The other approach is to use a numeric character entity reference.  For example the Java `char` with value `\246` has hexadecimal value `A6` ... and hence we can represent it in an XML document as `&x00A6;`

---

If you are using Java XML APIs to generate the XML, this should all be taken care of for you.

Comment: Thanks all, turns out that I can put &#x00A6; in the xml.